# Chain Rule for Partial Derivatives in convection-diffusion

Tags: chain-rule, linear-pde, partial-differential-equations

Suppose I have the following transformation: $$P(x,t)=G(x-vt,t)$$

How can I apply this to:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial P(x,t)}{\partial t}=-v\frac{\partial P(x,t)}{\partial x}+D \frac{\partial^2 P(x,t)}{\partial x^2}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an advection-diffusion equation. Let us write the change of variable as follows:
$$
P(x,t) =G(\xi,t),\qquad \xi = x-vt.
$$
Then, use the chain rule
\begin{aligned}
P_t &= G_\xi\xi_t + G_t = -v G_\xi + G_t \\
P_x &= G_\xi\xi_x = G_\xi \\
P_{xx} &= G_{\xi\xi}\xi_x = G_{\xi\xi} .
\end{aligned}
Finally, the heat equation $G_t = DG_{\xi\xi}$ is recovered.